# AWS DynamoBD NoSQL: many-to-many with composite keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I'm trying to start with NoSQL database and so started a simple dictionary project to train.

I am working on [Amazon Web Services DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/).

My dictionary needs to store words with their language, and their translations.
So in SQL I would have two tables, one for the words, one for the mapping of translations.

### 1. Many to many

According to Amazon's video ([here](https://youtu.be/PDQ3jbDyTQ4?t=32m20s)), to do a N to M relationship, we just need to create a table with a composite primary key :

- Partition key : the word
- Sort key : its translation

And a secondary index which PK and SK the table are swapped :

- Parition key : the sort key of the table (the translation)
- Sort key : partition key of the table (the word)

It makes sense.

### 2. Composite primary key

My words have a language, and it need to take part in the primary key, otherwise I will have collisions when the user enters a word that exists in two languages. So my word table primary key looks like this :

- Parition key : language
- Sort key : word

### 3. And... The problem

Now, I want to apply the N-to-M mapping strategy (1) with my table (2) ; and here is my problem, my table has a composite key. So I need to be able to "merge" my pair lang/word and I don't have a good feeling about that:

1. Use a concatenation of language and word is a solution, but I don't think it's Ok for the partition key (sort key yes according to the video)
2. Abandon the translation table and put all the translations in an array as a third field of the word table. This imply that I duplicate everything and that my queries will be OK in only one direction.
3. Create one table per combination of languages, which doesn't sounds very beautiful too.

So now I think I obviously missed something with NoSQL, or that my scheme is wrong somewhere. Just need a fresh eye to spot my mistakes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would design my key to concatenate the language and the word and then follow your approach to create a Global Secondary Index on the translated word. For example:
"en:vie" to represent the word "vie" in English and "fr:vie" to represent the word "vie" in French.

Why do you say that this is not an OK approach?

Comment: I think this approach makes sense, but as the partition key is a hash, it limits the usage of the table.

We will be able to query translations for a specific list of words which is OK, but if we want to query all translations of a given language we have to query the word table to get the list of word in the selected language, then insert it as parameter in another query against the translation table.

Maybe this approach is the good one with NoSQL, but to me that make a lot of data moving.

Comment: If you want to make queries for all words for a given language, you can add an additional attribute per item called Language. Then, create a Global Secondary Index where Language is the hash key and you'll be able to get the words for that language back in a query result. I have used this exact design pattern before. One concern is that tables and indexes are supposed to have well distributed keys to optimize throughout. Keys with uniform access patterns are best: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.UniformWorkload